# Why is Google Keep's use of background data suddenly through the roof?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, background-data, google-keep

I just got a warning from my provider that I had already used up 80% of this month's data plan. So I checked my data usage and saw that Google Keep had used a whopping 201 MB in background data, since april 8th.

Needless to say I immediately turned off background data, but the damage has already been done.

What on earth can have caused for Google Keep to use such an enormous amount of background data? I hardly even use it, only as a clipboard (since sharing to clipboard isn't always available, while sharing to Keep almost always is).

Also, in a case like this which looks like a malfunction, is there any chance for me to get a compensation from the app's maker - Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that would be a data leaking app as per April 8th. And I never saw that coming because I have a large amount of data package for myself but would go and check.

This is a hell lot of data being used up by such a tiny app. I mean in my phone 200mb+ data is either used up by Google Play store or a Browser app by which I downloaded files (audio, video, images etc). Otherwise I never saw such event.

However, if you want to contact Google about it. They would be waiting for the feedback and you can include this as the feedback message. But if you want them to get you some data package (maybe I got confused and mis understood your point of view for contact) then they won't do it.

Answer (score -3):

Haha, but it's obvious they won't! Dude, what do you expect? And yeah, if your Google Keep is eating your Data Packet, then stop using it as a Clipboard, because every single time you open it, sync starts. I never found this issue with my Keep. Turn off Google Sync; it's the best way!